# Minimum and Maximum Capacity of a channel

Tags: information-theory

There is this question in the Cover and Thomas book "Elements of Information Theory".

> Noise alphabets: Consider the channel Y = X + Z where X = {0, 1, 2, 3} and Z is uniformly distributed over three distinct integer values Z = {z1, z2, z3}.
>
> (a) What is the maximum capacity over all choices of the Z alphabet?
>       Give distinct integer values z1, z2, z3 and distribution on X achieving this.
>
> (b) What is the minimum capacity over all choices for the Z alphabet?
>       Give distinct integer values z1, z2, z3 and distribution on X achieving this.

The solution given was

> (a) Maximum capacity is C = 2 bits. Z = {10, 20, 30} and p(X) = (1/4, 1/4, 1/4, 1/4)
>
> (b) Minimum capacity is C = 1 bit. Z = {0, 1, 2} and p(X) = (1/2, 0, 0, 1/2)

I don't quite understand how to arrive at the solution.

My thoughts for this question are as follows.

The maximum capacity $C = max I(X + Z ; Y)$ over $P_x$. Therefore, $C = H(Y) - H(Y|X+Z)$, and $H(Y|X+Z) = 0$. So I should maximize $H(Y)$, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Alternatively, $C = max I(X; Y-Z) = H(X) - H(X|Y-Z)$. Similarly, $H(X|Y-Z) = 0$, so $max H(X)$ becomes $log 4 = 2$, so the maximum capacity is 2 bits. And this can be achieved when $P_x$ is a uniform distribution, i.e. $P_x = (1/4, 1/4, 1/4, 1/4)$. Is my understanding correct?

I don't understand why those values of Z were chosen, and how the minimum capacity is obtained. For example, why can't the capacity be 0 bits? I know it makes no sense to have a channel and not send any bits, but isn't 0 a valid minimum capacity?

Comment: For the maximum - think about it a bit more. What should the values of noise be so that the addition of noise makes no difference at all? Would $Z = \{100, 200, 300\}$ work?

Comment: Remember, in Information Theory, you know the statistics of the channel, and are allowed to mutually decide on a decoding scheme before communication.

Comment: If the decoder knows the input alphabets can only be $(0,1,2,3)$, then as long as Z is not very close to X, i.e. $(0,1,2)$, then there shouldn't be much difficulty decoding X, right? For example, if $Z = (0,1,2)$, then if X sent 0, the decoder wouldn't be able to decode it correctly. But if Z was larger, say $(100,200,300)$, or $(10,20,30)$, it should still be able to tell what X was. Is that correct?

Comment: So for the minimum case, if I want minimum capacity, then I want the decoder to be the most "confused", so if I let $Z = (0,1,2)$, then there will be the most confusion...

Comment: Aye, that's correct.

Now, the equation you're using above is wrong. $C = \max I(X;Y)$. Can you re-derive your result?

Comment: So Z makes no difference to the C equation?

Comment: Nope, $Y = X+Z$, so $Z$ has an effect. When you write $I(X+Z; Y)$, you're calculating $I(Y; Y)$.

Comment: So for the maximum capacity part, I have $C = \max I(X;Y) = H(X) - H(X|Y) = \max H(X)$, with $P_x = (1/4,1/4,1/4,1/4)$

Comment: For the minimum capacity part, I would try to minimize $H(X)$?

Comment: Not quite. You want to minimise the maximum of $H(X) - H(X|Y)$. The second term is no longer $0$, because there is some confusion. Also, it's generally a little easier to work with $H(Y) - H(Y|X)$, but that depends on the problem.

Comment: I'm a bit stuck at the minimum capacity part. I understand that $Z = (0,1,2)$ will create the most confusion for the decoder. I don't quite understand why the solution for $P_x$ is $(1/2,0,0,1/2)$. Using this X will give $(X,Z) = (0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(3,0),(3,1),(3,2)$, i.e. $Y = (0,1,2,3,4,5,6)$. Since the decoder knows X = (0,3), and Z is uniformly distributed, then chances that the decoder can correctly decode is 2/6. Or is it 1 if it knows the other values (1,2,4,5) are not possible since they are not in X?

Comment: If I choose $P_x = (1/2,1/2,0,0)$, then I have $(X,Z) = (0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(1,0),(1,1),(1,2)$, i.e. $Y = (0,1,2,3)$. In this case, Y can decode 2 of the 6 possible outputs correctly, $(0,1)$ will be incorrectly decoded as 1, and the rest are not in X. So is this case as good as the $P_x = (1/2,0,0,1/2)$ case or worse?

Comment: And if I take $P_x=(1/2,0,0,1/2)$, I then tried to calculate $I(X;Y) = H(Y) - H(Y|X)$. $H(Y|X) = p_x(0) H(Y|X = 0) + p_x(3) H(Y|X = 3) = (1/2)(-3/6)log(1/6) + (1/2)(-3/6) log(1/6) = (-1/2)log(1/6)$.

Comment: With $H(Y) = log6$, I got $I(X;Y) = log6 + (1/2)log(1/6) = (1/2)log6$, which is more than 1. Which part did I get wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your questions on the minimisation:

We can argue from the structure of the problem that the alphabet set of $Z$ must be $(a, a+1, a+2)$, for some integer $a$ (Ask me about this if this is unclear). Set $a = 0$ for convenience, since the decoder will know $a$, and can always subtract it.

Now, given this noise, we need to find the distribution $p_X$ that maximises $I(X;Y)$. I'll try to keep things fully analytic, no jumps of logic, no inspired guesswork.

$I(X;Y) = H(Y) - H(Y|X) = H(Y) - H(X+Z|X)$

$ = H(Y) - H(Z) = H(Y) - \log_2 3$

So we're looking for the distribution of $X$ : $(p_0, p_1, p_3, p_4)$ that maximises H(Y). There's a dirty old analytic way to do this, using lagrange multipliers. (Note, I'll be doing this in natural logs, because they don't leave a dirty constant. This doesn't make a difference to the maximiser.)

Now, the distribution of $Y$ in terms of that of $X$ is as follows (convince yourself of this):

$\left(p_0/3, (p_0 + p_1)/3, (p_0+p_1+p_2)/3, (p_1+p_2+p_3)/3, (p_2+p_3)/3, p_3/3 \right)$

We want to run the optimisation:
$$ \max_{(p_0, p_1, p_2,p_3)} \sum_{y=0}^5 -p_y\ln p_y$$
$$\text{Subject to } p_0 + p_1 + p_2 + p_3 = 1$$

Define $J = \sum_{y=0}^5 -p_y\log p_y + \lambda (p_0 + p_1 + p_2 + p_3 - 1)$

At the optimum:

$$\partial_{p_0} (J) = 0 \implies \log \left( (p_0)(p_1+p_0)(p_2+p_1+p_0) \right)  = 3\lambda - 3 \tag{1}$$

$$\partial_{p_1} (J) = 0 \implies \log \left((p_1+p_0)(p_2+p_1+p_0)(p_3+p_2+p_1)\right)  = 3\lambda - 3 \tag{2}$$

$$\partial_{p_2} (J) = 0 \implies \log \left((p_2+p_1+p_0)(p_3+p_2+p_1)(p_3+p_2)\right)  = 3\lambda - 3 \tag{3}$$

$$\partial_{p_3} (J) = 0 \implies \log \left((p_3)(p_3+p_2)(p_3+p_2+p_1)\right) = 3\lambda - 3 \tag{4}$$

$$\partial_{\lambda}(J) = 0 \implies p_0 + p_1 + p_2 + p_3 = 1 \tag{5}$$

This is not so bad to calculate. Look at all terms with $p_0$ in them. When the product $(p_0+p_1)\log(p_0+p_1)$ is differentiated, differentiating the log will leave you with a 1, and differentiating the outer $p_0 + p_1$ will leave you with just the log.

Now, $(1) - (2) = 0$. This implies:

$$\log \frac{p_0}{p_1 + p_2 + p_3} = 0 \iff p_0 = p_1 + p_2 + p_3 \tag{$\alpha$}$$

$(4) - (3) = 0$. This implies:

$$\log \frac{p_3}{p_0 + p_1 + p_2 } = 0 \iff p_3 = p_0 + p_1 + p_2 \tag{$\beta$}$$

Solve out the two equations above, and feed them into equation $(5)$ to get $p_0 = p_3 = 0.5$

At this, the distribution of $Y$ is uniform over 6 characters.

Therefore, $C = \max\limits_{p_X} I(X;Y) = \log_2 6 - \log _2 3 = 1$. Phew.

---

Try to see what this is structurally doing. Suppose $X$ was uniform, then under this noise, I would be able to tell when the input was $0$ or $3$ to much greater accuracy than if it was $1$ or $2$. Why? Because whenever $Y= 0$ I know that the input is $0$, and similarly for $Y=5, X=5$. So a 'good' distribution for communication under this noise would be weighed more at $0$ and $3$.

---

To answer the other questions you raised:

1. Capacity can be zero, sure. For example, take $Z$ to be uniform over $\{ 1, 2, \dots ,N\}$. Then the capacity heads to $0$ as $n \to \infty$
2. What you're trying to do here is this: You know that your noise is uniform over 3 letters. You don't know which letters. Suppose the noise was the worst possible. At what rate would I still be able to communicate? This is the minimum capacity. It's the smallest of the maximum rates at which I could talk subject to varying noise.
3. (From your comments) You've calculated $H(Y|X)$ incorrectly.

$H(Y|X) = H(X+Z|X) = H(Z|X) = H(Z)$

Where the second equality comes from the fact that if I'm given $X$, I can always subtract it from any other random variable with 100% accuracy, and the last equality because $Z$ and $X$ are independent.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for your detailed explanations! I think I was very much thrown off by the "minimum capacity" until I read your line "This is the minimum capacity. It's the smallest of the maximum rates at which I could talk subject to varying noise.". So we are actually still trying to find the maximum rate, just the minimum of all the maximum rates subject to the noise.

Comment: Same goes for the $P_x$, minimum capacity means we're trying to get the best coding scheme under the worst conditions, so Z should provide the most confusion to the decoder, and since X = (0,1,2,3), Z = (0,1,2) will be most confusing. And a $P_x$ weighted most at 0 and 3 gives the best coding scheme under the circumstance.